# Exporting nested dictionaries to csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary `archive` with several levels of nested dictionaries.

I'm trying to export `to_csv` one of the nested dictionaries which is a pandas dataframe. This will loop through the `'job code'` using the `'job code'` in the exported file name.

Essentially the dictionary is structured in these levels:

`archive` > `p_jobs` > `'job code'` > `metadata`

Where `'job code'` can be called anything.

To access I am trying to use:

```
    output_path = archive.paths["archive_path"]

    p_jobs = archive.p_jobs
    for job in p_jobs:
        jobs = p_jobs[job]

        for metadata in jobs:

            metadata.to_csv(path_or_buf=os.path.join(output_path, job), sep=',', index=False)
```

But the above is incorrect, how should I be obtaining the metadata dictionary. Note: under the `job_code` dictionary there are other nested dictionaries which I do not want to access.

------ Edited with an example

Here's an example of the nesting, I want to export each metadata dataframe through to_csv() named as the `p_job` e.g. A123.csv

```
archive = {'p_job': {'A123': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                        'A124': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                        'A12T': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                        'C176': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list}

                      }}
```

Comment: From what I understand, add another dictionary reference:

`metadata = jobs[metadata]
for data in metadata:
    ...................`

Comment: @DevangSanghani thank you for your comment, it probably gets me closer to the solution, but `print(data)` gives me the column headers of the dataframe

Comment: Maybe if could post the dictionary here. @Spatial Digger

Comment: dictionary example added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
archive = {'p_job': {'A123': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                    'A124': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                    'A12T': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list},
                    'C176': {'metadata':  df, 'images': a_list}
                    }
          }

p_jobs = archive['p_job']

for job in p_jobs:
    jobs = p_jobs[job]
    meta=jobs['metadata']
    meta.to_csv("./"+job, sep=",", index=False)
```

I could save metadata df as separate csv file

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     5 Jan 28 19:34 A123.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     5 Jan 28 19:34 A124.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     5 Jan 28 19:34 A12T.csv
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     5 Jan 28 19:34 C176.csv
(base) user@Mac ~ % cat A123.csv
a
10
```